# What correlation coefficient should I use?

Tags: correlation

I need to find the correlation between the use of ICT and EFL knowledge levels.
ICT data was collected on a yes/no survey and the results of the test are numeric. How do I proceed?

---

This is the data (If it helps) 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there, have you had a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: It would be better to provide the data as text rather than an image (use code formatting)

Comment: I'm voting to close because OP never clarified if the answer provided was sufficient for answering the question (thus requiring more detail).

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite broad; let's see if we can break it down. Do you have a screenshot of 3-4 rows of the data, and the column titles? It may be a question that can be answered with something as simple as a Google Sheet `correl` function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093990?hl=en

Using the data you've supplied, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTEWhJs75K0LLFf1SNDf9IacH7ANkoH_pX5-W-4E58m_Vw-Qi2sip70WDUBEZW0GFctrz9t6_ED0LiH/pubhtml?gid=1306469129&single=true) is the result:
[image: Google Sheets' CORREL function]

1. It can't correlate the Netherlands data because there is no variation in the Yes/No values (are you able to share more data with us?)
2. It appears there is a high correlation of `IWB` with `Vocabulary`. Does this fit your expectations?

Comment: As I am not allowed to give print screens, here is some data

         School s1 s2 s3
IWB             No Yes No
Computer   No Yes Yes
projector      No Yes No

School             s1   s2     s3
Listening M     9,3  9,9    9,9
Vocabulary M  8,9  10,7  9,8
Reading M      7,3   7,8   7,8

Comment: @Sabina does this help?